# getJSON not outputting the html data into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I try to output that getJSON in `console.log(data)` is fine, i see it, yet it doesn't go into the div as I am expecting to.

Trying this:

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?", 
{
  page:"Football", prop:"text"
}, function(data) {
    $(".modal-content").html(data);
});

<div class="modal-content"></div>
```

**NOTE:** console gives no error and div is empty

Comment: Try `$(".modal-content").html(data.parse.text['*']);` instead of `$(".modal-content").html(data);`

Comment: @DavidDomain bingo! Put that into an answer and I will accept it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access the `text` property of the returned object correctly. Just trying to set `.html(..` by passing the returned object will not work, because jquerys `.html()` method expects a function or a string as the parameter.

According to wikis [API:JSON version 2](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:JSON_version_2#The_future_of_.22version_1.22_JSON_response_format) you can add the following property to the options object passed to `$.getJSON`.

```
formatversion:2
```

> Eliminate useless indirection, e.g. `{"text":"..."}` instead of `{"text":{"*":"..."}}` and `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}` instead of `[{"name":"key1","*":"value1"},{"name":"key2","*":"value2"}]`.

So here is the correct anwser.

```
var location = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?";

$.getJSON(location, {
  page:"Football", 
  prop:"text", 
  formatversion: 2
}, function(data) {
    $(".modal-content").html(data.parse.text);
    //console.log(data.parse.text)
});
```